# Python dependency injection vs composition?

Tags: python, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I'm learning python and just wanted to confront two versions of the same code and ask which approach is better. Basically I have the Reputation class which should be bound to each Warrior object. My intuition tells me it would be the easiest to simply create Reputation instance during initialazing Warrior object. On the other hand it's against dependency injection. I would appreciate any feedback.

```
class Reputation:
    def __init__(self, reputation):
        self._reputation = reputation

    def rank(self):
        if self._reputation >= 10: return "basic"
        if self._reputation >= 20: return "mid"
        if self._reputation >= 30: return "advanced"

    def set(self, value):
         if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("Negative")
         self._reputation = value

    def get(self):
        return self._reputation
```

composition

```
class Warrior:
    def __init__(self, name: str, reputation: int = 0):
        self.name = name
        self._reputation = Reputation(reputation)

    @property
    def rank(self):
        return self._reputation.rank()

    @property
    def reputation(self):
        return self._reputation.get()

    @reputation.setter
    def reputation(self, value):
        self._reputation.set(value)

def main():
    warrior = Warrior("muah")
    warrior.reputation += 10
    print(warrior.rank)
    -- basic
```

Or dependency injection:

```
class Warrior:
    def __init__(self, name: str, reputation: Reputation):
        self.name = name
        self._reputation = reputation

    @property
    def rank(self):
        return self._reputation.rank()

    @property
    def reputation(self):
        return self._reputation.get()

    @reputation.setter
    def reputation(self, value):
        self._reputation.set(value)

def main():
    warrior_reputation = Reputation(reputation=11)
    warrior = Warrior("muah", reputation=warrior_reputation)
    warrior.reputation += 10
    print(warrior.rank)
    -- mid
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, it's always better to use dependency injection than composition , with DI way decouple your class with Reputation and better for  testing.